# floating point arm disassembly instructions

Tags: assembly, floating-point, arm, disassembly

I'm trying to recreate the following piece of arm disassembly in c++:

```
00003188    ed910a06    flds    s0, [r1, #24]
0000318c    edd10a07    flds    s1, [r1, #28]
00003190    ec800a02    fstmias r0, {s0-s1}
00003194        4770    bx  lr
00003196        bf00    nop
```

Firstly, is s0 a single precession register? And what do flsl and fstmias do. I tried the following code but it doesn't produce the same result:

```
float s0 = r1[6];
float s1 = r1[7];
```

What's wrong with what I tried?

Comment: [fstmias](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/Bcfchhif.html) stores single precision numbers at the adress specified by `r0` (IA = increment address). So you need `r0[0] = s0; r0[1] = s1;` if that is how you want to translate it... (Or `mem[r0]=s0;mem[r0+4]=s1;` I dunno how the surrounding code looks).

Comment: @user786653: why don't you post that as an answer? If you can also explain the `bx lr` part, you got everything covered.

Answer (score 4):

Since it's a very trivial function, let's take it line by line. I am going to assume that you posted the *complete* function.

```
00003188    ed910a06    flds    s0, [r1, #24]
```

The [`FLDS`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/Bcfcdfdd.html) is on this form: "FLD<precision>{cond} Fd, [Rn{, #offset}]", with precision as s (=single precision). As the documentation states this loads a single precision floating value located at `r1 + 24` into `s0`.

```
0000318c    edd10a07    flds    s1, [r1, #28]
```

And another load, this time from `r1 + 28` (this corresponds to what you write with `r1[7]`).

```
00003190    ec800a02    fstmias r0, {s0-s1}
```

[`FSTMIAS`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/Bcfchhif.html) lists "FSTM<addressmode><precision>{cond} Rn,{!} VFPregisters". Here you have  addressmode = IA, which means "Increment address After each transfer" and precision = single . This instruction stores the specified registers to the address specified in `r0` Incrementing the address after each store. In other words it stores `s0` at `[r0]` and `s1` at `[r0+4]`.

```
00003194        4770    bx  lr
```

[BX](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/Bcfchhif.html) is branch (and optionally change back to ARM mode) to register value - the preferred way of returning from functions (see section 5.1 [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs414/2001fa/armcallconvention.pdf)). In this case the register is the link register which holds the return address.

```
00003196        bf00    nop
```

No OPeration. Does nothing, Usually inserted to align functions in memory.

The [calling convention](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs414/2001fa/armcallconvention.pdf) for ARM-THUMB (section 4.1) states that the first four arguments are passed in r0-r3 (== a1-a4) and we can see from the disassembly that r0 and r1 are used so the function takes 2 parameters. It is unclear whether the function returns a value (the same as the first input) or doesn't return a value. You will have to look at call sites to figure this out.

In C parlance we have a function that takes two pointer values as input, loads two `float`s from offsets 24 and 28 from the second parameter and stores them at offsets 0 and 4 in the first. Without further knowledge of the program it is impossible to tell if the parameters are supposed to be arrays, structures or something else.

Assuming they are arrays a translation to C is trivial:

```
void mystery_function(float* dst, const float* src) {
    dst[0] = src[6];
    dst[1] = src[7];
}
```